# How to launch `python -m MY_MODULE` in debug mode in pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I have a script that can only be run as `python -m path.to.my_script`, due to the use of relative imports. Running it as `python path/to/my_script.py` gives "Attempted relative import with no known parent package" error.

How can I launch such script in PyCharm debug mode?

Comment: Use proper imports?

Comment: relative imports are another kind of proper, officially supported imports.

Comment: and yet you need to jump through hoops and create dummy scripts :)

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to launch a dummy file importing the script with absolute path. So I have created `path/to/dummy.py` and did `import path.to.my_script`, then launched dummy.py in debugger.

I've tried configuring interpreter options in run configurations, but couldn't figure it out.